# Change the text by Raphael

Tags: javascript, raphael

I want to make a small animation by changing the text. That's how it looks:

```
var t6= p.text(200,500).attr({
   "font-size" : 25,
   "fill" : "#000000",
   "text": "Start",
   "opacity": "100"    
 });



 t6.animate({
   "text": "Stop"
 }, 1000, "linear");
```

Unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: "Does not work" is _never_ a sufficient problem description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use print instead of text and declare a second variable with the value "Stop", and set it to hide. During your animation, you will just have to set an apparition path.

More info here : http://cancerbero.mbarreneche.com/raphaeltut/#heading_toc_j_67
(the animated text example is exactly what you need)